# Creating a UIView to be displayed in multiple UIViewControllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I am creating a simple little popup view, similar to the popup that appears when you push the volume buttons. I would like to display an instance of that popup view in different view controllers. I have been pondering a couple approaches, but I would like to know what is the best approach, taking into account MVC, complexity, and otherwise 'good' practices.

Currently, I am creating and displaying this UIView from within my UIViewController. I justified that approach since it's really a small view and I do a lot of work with it to modify its behavior in that VC, so that code was already going to be in the VC. Essentially, I make a frame, set the background, apply corner radius, add text to it, apply motion effects, then make it fade in then later fade out. I could copy and paste the code into my other VCs but that's obviously a bad approach.

I could create a subclass of UIView and I'm sure I could use drawRect to draw it, but I'm not sure exactly how to add that view to the VC exactly in the middle, unless I drag out a view to my VCs and change its class. But if I do that I can do most everything in Interface Builder anyways, which would be preferred especially if I can use Auto Layout to always keep it centered. But, I'd need to copy and paste that UIView into each VC and hide it - that doesn't sound good.

I could create a subclass of UIView and instead of drawing with drawRect, implement a method that creates the UIView and returns it. Then in the VCs I just call that method and add the view it returns as a subview. I've never done this, and I'm not sure if that's an appropriate approach.

What is a plausible approach to implementing such a view that can be thrown on screen from any of my VCs? Thanks!

Note that this view should always be the same size, in the center of the screen, not tied to any specific VC. It should remain on screen unaffected by transitions and such. It closely mimics the Volume popup.

Comment: If this popup view has a single target throughout your app, (and not specific view controllers), subclassing (singleton approach) is the best. Even, if it has view-controller specific actions, with a little bit of coding for `delegate`s, you can easily re-use it everywhere. Another option, if you want it to persist on the screen at the same position, irrespective of view/controllers (and transitions), you might add your code to appDelegate, and add the view to your app's window, instead of view controller. Then, from each VC, you can call the appDelegate's methods to handle this popup.

Comment: I have a hard time imagining worse advice than that in n00bProgrammer's comment above. Singleton? Really? Don't go that route.

Comment: Indeed, the popup does need to persist through transitions - it's not specific to any VC. It 'feels' wrong to put it in the app delegate though.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to display that same popup in multiple view controllers.

I expect that you mean you'd like to have separate instances of that same class in multiple view controllers. A given view can have only one superview, so it can't exist in more than one view at a time.

> I'm not sure exactly how to add that view to the VC exactly in the middle

It's easy to center a view in its superview. To center horizontally, subtract the width of the view from the width of the parent. Divide the result by 2. That's your X coordinate. Same goes for the Y coordinate, except that you'd obviously use the heights.

An even easier method is to create a point by dividing the superview's width and height each by 2. Set your view's `center` property to that point.

> What is a plausible approach to implementing such a view that can be thrown on screen from any of my VCs?

Don't try to reuse the *same* view. There's no need for that, and trying to pass it around between controllers will really complicate your code. Just have any controller that needs to display your popup create its own copy.

Remember, views are the interface to the data that's stored in your model -- they can display that data or let you interact with the model, but they shouldn't store app state themselves. Given that, there's *no reason* that you'd need to use the very same view in more than one view controller. As long as your pop up gets its data from the right place, you can have as many instances of it as you like.

If your popup really is separate from the content of any of your view controllers, another possible strategy is to use view controller containment. You can create one view controller that handles just the "app-wide" stuff, like this popup, and have it load and unload the various other view controllers as it's children. I'd caution against trying this, though -- it's probably more complicated than you need and surely more complicated than you should attempt right now given that you seem to still be getting your sea legs.

Comment: Sorry for not making that clearer. Indeed I do want multiple instances of it as opposed to trying to literally reuse the same exact view. Create an instance, display it, make it disappear after a few seconds. I would like to code it such that I can pass it the string I want displayed - "Success" or "Failed" for example. I'm just not sure which approach to take to actually implement it.

Comment: Keep it simple. Use standard parts where you can -- UILabel for instance.

Comment: I like simple. So should it be just a regular method in a separate class that creates a UIView and returns it - no need to be a subclass of UIView?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like [MBProgressHUD](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD) is what you're looking for. [FFCircularProgressView](https://github.com/elbryan/FFCircularProgressView) might also help.